# i have an issue with posting on facebook article with joomla cms

Tags: facebook, plugins, joomla, share, linkedin-api

I am trying to make a web page with joomla CMS.

I have tried every possible free extension for share, like on facebook, twitter and linkedin...BUT whenever i install another plugin which is not  related to social plugins all the article's posts on facebook change images, links and titles.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using the K2 component.

K2 in in nutshell is an extended article manager that includes many more features such as a voting, comments and sharing system. The social buttons include Facebook, Twitter and Google+.

I would strongly advice it:

http://getk2.org/

Comment: Do you think the problem is the database? Because  a few days ago i got a fatal  error. And after that incident everything goes wrong including the problem with the posts

Comment: @thrylos_7: I'm not sure what plugins you have alreadyu tried but I doubt very much it is a database related problem. As I said in my answer, try K2 as you might like it.

Comment: I have tried it as you said and and it seems it be a good idea. The only problem is the fact that we have to pay for almost every module. Have you tried the smart-news template?

Comment: @thrylos_7: No, I haven't used a template called Smart News. K2 is free by the way.

Comment: I know k2 component is free by the most features needed for this component are not free. As you said the social buttons facebook, twitter and google+ are included but after a few days do not work. Actually, i use greek language for the articles and if you try the like button of facebook provided by K2 seems to be faulty (not share, because is different component). The page is www.sport-venue.com. Do you have a any idea ?